# Bootstrap button margin/padding different after dotnet publish

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, webpack, asp.net-core-2.0, angular5

I am working on an Angular 5, ASP.NET Core 2.0, Bootstrap project with a webpack bundler. I'm having trouble trying to figure out why some button placements are different between running my site in Visual Studio vs running it after a `dotnet publish`.

Here is the issue, my buttons are squished together.

[image: Good button placement]

This is how it should look; notice the spacing between the buttons:

[image: Good button placement]

The buttons look correct when I run in Visual Studio, either as standalone or in IIS express. However, on my live website (dotnet publish), the buttons are squished. This happens in other areas of the site where buttons are placed side-by-side. Now, I could add styling to correct the behavior, but it doesn't make sense until I eliminate the existing discrepancy.

**What I've tried**

1. Check for different CSS styles for the elements. I've checked my live site and my debugging site, and they are exactly the same. But how can that be true if they look different?
2. Since I am usually in Debug mode in Visual Studio, and my live site is the Release version, I tried running Release mode in Visual Studio. It still looks correct running it this way.
3. I know that my live site ultimately uses `dotnet publish` to generate my site. So, through Powershell, I ran `dotnet publish` and `dotnet run` and viewed it on `localhost`. Aha! I get squished buttons.

Yet, I still inspect my elements in Chrome between each version, and I still have different button placements with the same CSS. I can't even find out why there is padding between the buttons in the correct version, there is no margin/padding on them! Not sure what else to try.

The HTML is simple:

```
<div *ngIf="user?.username">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="likeClick()">Like</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="comment()">Reply</button>
</div>
```

And I'm using `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"`

Comment: Could it be that the [root font size](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/) is different? The text looks a little smaller in the bottom image, and Bootstrap uses `rem` units for dimensions.

Comment: I cropped the images with Windows Snipping Tool, so they are scaled a little differently to fit in the question post's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems that because my HTML is entered as

```
<div *ngIf="user?.username">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="likeClick()">Like</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="comment()">Reply</button>
</div>
```

the newlines between buttons create a space character as I'm debugging. That explains why I couldn't see any CSS margins or widths in Chrome dev tools for the gap; I got lucky and accidentally selected the space character with my cursor.

I'm guessing that the hot reloading with webpack has something to do with this. The space character goes away if I remove the newline, and it also goes away if I apply margin to the buttons, which I think is interesting.

So, I now just add `.btn-toolbar` to any button grouping that represents a toolbar and style as I wish:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" *ngIf="user?.username">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="likeClick()">Like</button>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" (click)="comment()">Reply</button>
</div>
```

.

```
.btn-toolbar > button {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.btn-toolbar > button:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```